# Scroll Positioning for Overflow Container

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to set (horizontal) scroll position of overflow container?

**JsFiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/JeaffreyGilbert/FVrtx/

**Preview:**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`container.scrollLeft = 1000;`

Comment: In that case full solution without jQuery will be like that: http://jsfiddle.net/FVrtx/2/

Answer (score 1):

Use [ScrollTo jQuery Plugin](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/)

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/FVrtx/1/

```
$('.wrap').scrollTo('50%', 800);
```